# Using A Swift Framework In Kotlin

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin

Background: I have a large swift application with a substantial amount of business logic for an app. We have recently begun work on an android clone of the app (in Kotlin).

I would like to refactor the business logic into several swift frameworks and then export the swift frameworks for android. I understand only the swift stdlib can be used in shared code.

I seen some examples like [this one](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Android.md) that show how to run swift code on an android device. However I have also read that swift does nothing to help the bridging to java. I've seen some swift -> kotlin converters, but I don't want to do that.

tl;dr; What is the best way to run a swift framework on android and interface with it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Your question mixes several goals in ways that are unlikely to ever result in a productive outcome.  You have several choices:

1. Develop in Swift on Android.  Apple's own advice for starting down this path is at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/Android.md  but certainly this will be a lengthy journey far beyond what Apple initiates in that introduction.
2. Meticulously & faithfully duplicate the Swift source code's functionality in Kotlin source code and forget about all interest in Swift frameworks (especially Swift frameworks from Apple, because they will never be on Android).
3. Rearchitect your application so that it uses VIPER (View, Interactor, Presenter, Entity, and Routing) software architecture so that Swift on iOS/MacOS/WatchOS/tvOS is quarantined into view & presenter zones and so that Kotlin on Android is quarantined into view & presenter zones but business logic written in a portable lingua-franca language (say, C++) is quarantined in interactor zone.  This is substantially similar to the MVVM software architecture utilized by Xamarin.Mac & Xamarin.Android to quarantine UI stuff away from business-logic stuff (although usually the language utilized everywhere in a nonForms Xamarin app is C# throughout).  VIPER simply goes to the Nth degree further toward these strict-separation-of-concerns goals than MVVM tries to go.